# ios swift show custom view below Navigation controler

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, custom-view

I am working with iOS swift application , I have create a custom view . 
I want that view will display on bottom/ below of my navigation controller.

I have below case for that view:

1. Portrait with Navigation controller
2. Landscape with  Navigation controller
3. Portrait without Navigation controller
4. Landscape without Navigation controller

If I have navigation controller it display bottom of that if I have not navigation controller it display bottom of status bar accordingly.

Comment: post image or diagram of your requirement , image speaks more than words

Answer (score 0):

add top constraint with constant = 0
tell me how you want to do it and I'll help you with it (storyboard or code)